# Lint does not check missing translations

Tags: android, string, locale, lint, language-translation

I use Lint to check for missing translations in strings.xml (in values-de, values-en, values-hu, etc.). However, I noticed that if there are no strings in another language in other strings.xml files, Lint does not find the missing translations.

Example:

values/strings.xml:

```
<string name="abc">test</string>
```

values-en/strings.xml:

```
<!--empty-->
```

-> not work

values/strings.xml:

```
<string name="dummy">dummy</string>

<string name="abc">test</string>
```

values-en/strings.xml:

```
<string name="dummy">dummy</string>
```

-> works

Is there any way to force Lint to control that translation for string called "abc" is missing without adding dummy string? Unfortunately, even empty strings.xml files are not enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a string only in `strings.xml` try that.

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="MissingTranslation">

    <string translatable="false" name="abc">test</string>

</resources>
```

Comment: My problem si opposite, I want Lint to find missing translations if other strings.xml (in values-en, values-de etc.) is empty or not exists.